# Spike a single request after certain interval in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I am running a 5000 users soak test with 300 RPS using JMeter. Test duration is 1 hour. How do I spike a single request to 300 after certain interval (20 minutes)? I also want to hold that that spike for 2-3 minutes and then revert to normal load.

I tried Synchronizing Timer but it generates spike for every iteration. My requirement is to generate a spike after 20 minutes only.

Answer (score 0):

My expectation is that you should consider switching to [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/), it allows you to flexibly and precisely control the throughput in terms of "requests per second" so you can define how many RPS you want to have for this or that test phase.

An example implementation of your test scenario would be something like:

[image]

replace `1` with the desired RPS value for the "normal" load.

A good idea would be using the Throughput Shaping Timer in [combination](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ThroughputShapingTimer/#Special-Property-Processing) with the [Concurrency Thread Group](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ConcurrencyThreadGroup/) - this way JMeter will be able to kick off extra threads in order to reach/maintain the desired load.

You can install both plugins using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

[image]